# How to get process state?

Tags: java, exec, processbuilder

How can I get process state, that is it running or completed.

I am creating new process through:

```
processBuilder();
```

Comment: *"Any help will be appreciated.

thanks:"*  A '?' added to the question would be more likely to elicit help than adding such noise.  BTW - what 'state' are you referring to?  For 'completion' look to [`Process.waitFor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29) & [`exitValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#exitValue%28%29).

Comment: May be [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11510642/2894369) can help you.

Comment: Java comes with a very comprehensive documentation, check out the [Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) and [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) objects. If you still have an issue, show that you've read the documentation and improve your question. And FYI: its `ProcessBuilder` not `processBuilder`.

Comment: You really should accept an answer. As it is, this near duplicate question should be closed. Please be a little more polite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct method available that can provide you the state of the process if you use use the `waitFor` then your current thread will wait until the process terminates.
So you can use `exitValue` function wrapped in function something like this,

```
public static boolean isProcessRunning(Process process) 
{
    try 
    {
        process.exitValue();
        return false;
    } 
    catch(IllegalThreadStateException e) 
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And then you can continue doing other work and call above method to check the state as and when needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2");
Process p = pb.start();
```

followed by

```
p.exitValue() //throws an IllegalThreadStateException - if the subprocess represented by                //this Process object has not yet terminated.
```

A shameless copy and paste job from the documentation, btw. Always a good place to start.